How to control echarts pie chart selected data distance from center
Current selected data display
currently when selected the pie chart data it display like this. I want it to display like when it was hover. which is like below pic.
desired result.
I have tried the combination in the docs, through series-pie.select.itemStyle but still fail to get the desired result.
thank you in advance.


const option: EChartsOption = {
  color: returnColor,
  tooltip: {
    trigger: "axis",
  },
  legend: {
    show: false, // Hides the legend
  },

  labelLine: {
    show: false,
  },
  series: [{
    top: "20%", // Adjust as necessary
    name: t("home.brands"),
    type: "pie",
    center: ["50%", "32%"],
    radius: ["70%", "100%"],
    selectedMode: true,
    select: {
      itemStyle: {
        borderJoin: 'miter',
        borderMiterLimit: 10,
      }
    },
    data,
    label: {
      show: true,
      position: "center",
      fontSize: 20,
      fontWeight: "bold",
      formatter: () => {
        const iconStyle =
          overAllFilter.vehicleInput === "HYUN" ?
          "HYUNDAI" :
          overAllFilter.vehicleInput ?
          overAllFilter.vehicleInput :
          "global";
        const name =
          overAllFilter.vehicleInput === "HYUN" ?
          "HYUNDAI" :
          overAllFilter.vehicleInput ?
          overAllFilter.vehicleInput :
          "";
        return iconStyle === "global" ?
          `{${iconStyle}|}` :
          `{${iconStyle}|}\n{name|${name}}`;
      },
      textStyle: {
        rich: {
          global: {},
          BMW: {
            backgroundColor: {
              image: "/logo/brand/bmw.webp",
            },
            width: 90,
            height: 50,
          },
          BYD: {
            backgroundColor: {
              image: "/logo/brand/byd.webp",
            },
            width: 90,
            height: 50,
          },
          HYUNDAI: {
            backgroundColor: {
              image: "/logo/brand/hyundai.webp",
            },
            width: 70,
            height: 50,
          },
          JLR: {
            backgroundColor: {
              image: "/logo/brand/jlr.webp",
            },
            width: 70,
            height: 50,
          },
          name: {
            color: "#fff",
            fontSize: 20,
            position: "center",
          },
        },
      },
    },
    emphasis: {
      label: {
        show: true,
        fontSize: 40,
        fontWeight: "bold",
        formatter(item) {
          const entry = data.find((obj) => obj.name === item.name);
          const iconStyle = entry ? .icon ? entry ? .icon : "defaultIcon";
          return `{${iconStyle}|}\n {name|${entry?.name}} `;
        },
        rich: {
          BMW: {
            backgroundColor: {
              image: "/logo/brand/bmw.webp",
            },
            width: 90,
            height: 50,
            align: "center",
          },
          HYUNDAI: {
            backgroundColor: {
              image: "/logo/brand/hyundai.webp",
            },
            width: 70,
            height: 50,
          },
          BYD: {
            backgroundColor: {
              image: "/logo/brand/byd.webp",
            },
            width: 90,
            height: 50,
          },
          JLR: {
            backgroundColor: {
              image: "/logo/brand/jlr.webp",
            },
            width: 70,
            height: 50,
          },
          name: {
            backgroundColor: "#222338",
            color: "#fff",
            fontSize: 20,
            position: "center",
          },
        },
      },
    },
  }, ],
};




Can you share the code you tried?

@Mustafa Hi, I edited the question with the code.

I have reviewed your code to help you, I have tried it on echarts. However, I cannot give a clear answer because I do not understand exactly what you want. Since you are using pie chart, you need to edit this part as ''item''. tooltip: {trigger: "item",},

Distance from center of selected data can be controled via selectedOffset. But this is not exactly what is shown in your pictures. I dont think there is a nice built in way to achieve your desired result for select. Its only possible for emphasis with the properties scale and scaleSize.
That beeing said, you can use the selectchanged event and a second pie series representing the selected items.
Example:
const data = [
  { value: 1048, name: 'Search Engine' },
  { value: 735, name: 'Direct' },
  { value: 580, name: 'Email' },
  { value: 484, name: 'Union Ads' },
  { value: 300, name: 'Video Ads' }
];

option = {
  series: [
    {
      id: 'main',
      type: 'pie',
      radius: ['40%', '70%'],
      label: { show: false },
      labelLine: { show: false },
      selectedMode: 'multiple',
      selectedOffset: 0,
      data: data
    }
  ]
};

myChart.on('selectchanged', function (params) {
  const selectedIndices = params.selected.length ? params.selected[0].dataIndex : [];
  const newData = structuredClone(data);
  for (let index in newData) {
    if (!selectedIndices.includes(Number(index))) {
      newData[index].itemStyle = { color: 'transparent' };
    }
  }
  myChart.setOption({series: [{id: 'main'}]}, {replaceMerge: ['series']});
  myChart.setOption({
    series: [{}, {
      id: 'selected',
      type: 'pie',
      radius: ['40%', '75%'],
      animation: false,
      silent: true,
      label: { show: false },
      labelLine: { show: false },
      data: newData,
    }]
  });
});

